What is China's current official position vis-a-vis Myanmar, as of 2024?
Until recently I thought that China was least roughly favorable to Myanmar's government. This was based on China's UN vetos as well as the presence of significant Chinese heavy weapons of recent vintage in Myanmar's arsenal *.
However, I was surprised to learn that some of Myanmar's military reverses on the Chinese border in 2023 were because some rebel groups have tacit Chinese backing.

From October until December of 2023, the Three Brotherhood Alliance (3BHA), gained control of more than 20,000 square kilometers (7,722 square miles) of territory, including key border crossings and trade routes between China and Myanmar. China leveraged the 3BHA’s offensive — known as Operation 1027 to mark the month and day it began —  to crush scam syndicates on its border, especially those run by the Myanmar military’s Border Guard Force (BGF) in Kokang.

Reuters Dec 2023

China, a key junta ally that also has close relations with some ethnic Chinese militias in the borderlands, has been riled by Myanmar's inability to shut down online scam centres along the frontier that have become a scourge across Southeast Asia.

I know there is an aspect of concern about "pig butchering" and its impact on Chinese citizens.
There is a wiki page on China-Myanmar relations but frankly it left me more confused than anything, not least because I am only curious about the last 4-5 years and because the page over-focusses on individual events.
Question:  Has the Chinese government recently communicated how it considers its relations with Myanmar's government?

*
List of equipment
Sipri arms transfer database
gave me this


Well, officially China just wants peace and their interests preserved.

Following his meeting with the Myanmar junta chief Min Aung Hlaing on Wednesday, Wang said Beijing “opposes chaos and conflicts in Myanmar” and hopes the country will increase efforts to stabilize the situation along the China-Myanmar border.
“Wang Yi expressed his hope that Myanmar will earnestly safeguard the safety of Chinese personnel and projects in Myanmar, maintain peace and stability along the China-Myanmar border, step up joint efforts to crack down on cross-border crimes, and create a safe environment for bilateral exchanges and cooperation,” the Chinese government said in its official readout.
For its part, Myanmar’s military government said China supports its “endeavors in implementing the five-point roadmap for ensuring peace and stability of the state and development and making preparations to hold a free and fair multiparty democratic general election.”
While Myanmar’s state-run Global New Light of Myanmar newspaper claimed that Beijing vowed to support a promised election, which the military government has said will be held in 2025, the Chinese readout didn’t include such details.
Some analysts say this difference reflects how Myanmar’s military government and the Chinese government view the supposed “election plan.”
“For the Myanmar military and its leader Min Aung Hlaing in particular, the elections are existential, but China probably remains very skeptical about the likelihood of an election being held since the military government controls less than half of Myanmar’s territory at the moment,” Hunter Marston, an adjunct research fellow at La Trobe University in Australia, told VOA by phone.

They don't seem too committal to the Myanmar military government as such.
Like in Pakistan, China hopes for a "CMEC" in Myanmar (too). According to [foreign] analysts China wants to

ensure the necessary political stability for implementing the China Myanmar Economic Corridor (CMEC), Beijing’s primary strategic interest in Myanmar. CMEC and its two parallel oil and gas pipelines traversing Myanmar from Rakhine State in the southwest to Shan State in the northeast are China’s solution to resolving its Malacca Dilemma. The Malacca Dilemma is China’s strategic vulnerability, where an estimated 80 per cent of China’s imported oil travels through the Straits of Malacca, leaving it susceptible to naval blockades by adversaries.

(The "Malacca dilemma" is a terminology used  by the Chinese leadership itself, albeit by former President Hu Jintao. The equivalent of the Gwadar port in Myanmar seems to be Kyaukpyu.)

A bit more transpired recently in the position statements of China and of the 3-brotherhood alliance (3BA).

The “three bottom lines,” articulated by Chinese Foreign Minister Wang Yi in August, call for Myanmar to avoid civil strife, remain part of ASEAN, and prevent external interference.

This was for instance reflected in the MNDAA position (one of the 3BA):

“Our political red line is not to form alliances or work together with those who are against China,” read the statement, which was briefly posted Sept. 4 and reposted on Sept. 19.

VOA comments that

the MNDAA is being pushed to sever ties with opposition forces that Beijing views as having U.S. support.
China used its economic and political leverage when it reportedly cut off trade and supplies to Laukkai, the capital of the Kokang region, to create distance between the MNDAA and the National Unity Government (NUG) — the pro-democracy shadow government leading the fight against the ruling junta.

